# Can every finite group be presented as an Fp group?

Tags: finite-groups, computational-algebra

If we have a finite group $G$, then  we know that $G$ is a quotient of some free group, say $F$, on some free set, say $X$.

Now, let $N$ have this: $G\cong F/N$, where $N$ is the normal closure of $R$ (some finite set of relators) in $F$.

Is it "safe" to say that $G \cong \langle X |R \rangle $ (or even $G = \langle X |R \rangle $)? Which leads to say $G$ is finitely presented group!

Thanks for advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "safe". The notation $G\simeq\langle X|R\rangle$ means $G\simeq F(X)/N(R)$ **by definition**. And yes, there's a theorem that every finite group is finitely presented.

Comment: @freakish It means that: is it true that $N$ with that property always exists?

Comment: With what property? Are you asking if every finite group is finitely presented? That's really confusing. Plus: what does "Fp" stand for in the title?

Comment: $N$ is the normal closure of $R$ in $F$(so the existence of $R$ is also questioned) AND $G \cong F/N$

Comment: If $G$ is **any** group and $X\subseteq G$ is a set of generators then there's a unique epimorphism $\phi:F(X)\to G$ such that $\phi(x)=x$ for $x\in X$. Thus the first isomorphism theorem applies and $G\simeq F(X)/N$ where $N=\ker(\phi)$ clearly exists. You can take $R=N$.

Comment: @freakish, Thanks for this explanation, I know that this is came immediately from the definition of "free on some set"; Yet how can we "extract" explicitly $R$, the set of relators, from that definition you gave me, $N= ker(\phi )$?

Comment: $R$ is just a set of generators of $N$. You don't need to extract it. You can simply take $R=N$ and you're done. Now if you want to prove that a given presentation is for example finite then indeed you have to show that $N$ is a finitely generated group, meaning that you can choose $R$ to be a finite subset of $N$. There is no general method of doing that and it often requires case-by-case approach. For example here's how you show that every finite group is finitely presented: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1677579/proof-of-every-finite-group-is-finitely-presented

Comment: @freakish , So, eventually it´s not a proof that every finite group can be finitely presented, I mean if that requires a case-by-case approach? In other hand the link you sent me is really around what my question is all about, many many thanks

Comment: No, there is a proof that every finite group is finitely presented. It is one of the cases. But there is no general method, meaning you cannot use the method for finite groups in order to check other situations.

Comment: @freakish, can you please explain what is "homomorphism extending the identity map of" ?

Answer (score 0):

Let $G$ be a finite group, and so its Cayley table is finite. Construct finitely presented group $F$ with generators elements in $G$, and relators $abc^{-1}$ if ab=c in the Cayley table.

Comment: the problem is: how to construct $F$? is there a general algorithm?